Why my postgresql perfomance getting worse after changing default parametes
I changed my postgresql server parameters to tune it for a query but I get worse result than default settings.Here is my changed parameters and explain result:
# pgTune suggested settings
shared_buffers = 2560MB
effective_cache_size = 7680MB
maintenance_work_mem = 640MB
work_mem = 12MB
max_wal_size = 4GB

and here are results:
# explain analyze result before tuning 
Result  (cost=11618.77..15868.77 rows=100000 width=50) (actual time=249.507..309.305 rows=109800 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1, temp read=417 written=419
->  Sort  (cost=11618.77..11868.77 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=249.502..276.241 rows=109800 loops=1)
     Sort Key: actor.actor_id, s1."time"
     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3336kB
     Buffers: shared hit=1, temp read=417 written=419
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1262.95 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=0.551..42.765 rows=109800 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=1
           ->  Function Scan on generate_series s1  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.524..0.703 rows=1098 loops=1)
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.20 rows=100 width=10) (actual time=0.000..0.011 rows=100 loops=1098)
                 Buffers: shared hit=1
                 ->  Subquery Scan on actor  (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=100 width=10) (actual time=0.020..0.086 rows=100 loops=1)
                       Buffers: shared hit=1
                       ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=100 width=118) (actual time=0.019..0.064 rows=100 loops=1)
                             Buffers: shared hit=1
                             ->  Seq Scan on actor actor_1  (cost=0.00..445666.24 rows=26213424 width=118) (actual time=0.018..0.046 rows=100 loops=1)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.251 ms
Execution Time: 319.925 ms
(19 rows)


# explain analyze result after changing parameters
Result  (cost=9567.77..13817.77 rows=100000 width=50) (actual time=280.372..340.972 rows=109800 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1
->  Sort  (cost=9567.77..9817.77 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=280.363..294.594 rows=109800 loops=1)
     Sort Key: actor.actor_id, s1."time"
     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 11414kB
     Buffers: shared hit=1
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1262.95 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=0.633..43.263 rows=109800 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=1
           ->  Function Scan on generate_series s1  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.600..0.806 rows=1098 loops=1)
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.20 rows=100 width=10) (actual time=0.000..0.011 rows=100 loops=1098)
                 Buffers: shared hit=1
                 ->  Subquery Scan on actor  (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=100 width=10) (actual time=0.025..0.092 rows=100 loops=1)
                       Buffers: shared hit=1
                       ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=100 width=118) (actual time=0.024..0.069 rows=100 loops=1)
                             Buffers: shared hit=1
                             ->  Seq Scan on actor actor_1  (cost=0.00..445666.24 rows=26213424 width=118) (actual time=0.022..0.051 rows=100 loops=1)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.247 ms
Execution Time: 355.548 ms
(19 rows)

Here is my query on dvdrental sample database :
explain (analyze,buffers) SELECT 
actor.first_name, 
s1.time as time, 
random() * (100-0) + 0 AS cpu_usage, 
random() * (30-26) + 26 * 1024 AS average_mhs, 
random() * (90-50) + 50 AS temperature, 
random() * (100-0) + 0 AS fan 
FROM generate_series(
  '2018-10-14', 
  '2021-10-15', 
INTERVAL '1 day') AS s1(time) 
CROSS JOIN(
SELECT 
   actor_id,
   first_name, 
   last_name 
FROM actor limit 100 
) actor
ORDER BY 
actor.actor_id, 
s1.time;

While I used limit 2000 or higher instead of limit 100 the result gets worse too.

Is that difference even reliable?  Looks like it could just be noise.

Yes, try a couple of times and see how much the execution times vary.
